# Add static comment on every question answered on form

Tags: knockout.js

I have a form with lot of questions. On every question answered I need to filled a predefined string information (called comments) in an readonly textarea. Is there any better solution?

[image]

I made a comment object (to store all the comments) and a comment string and on every question answered I am appending the comment from comment object to comment string.

```
var comment = "";
var CommentObj = { "comment1": `Your favourite color is ${favoriteColor}`}

comment = self.favoriteColor() ? comment + CommentObj[comment1] : comment.replace(CommentObj[comment1], '');
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You showed some code but it's not clear where you're running that.

Comment: @pabrams I am not getting any error. I just need a solution for a module that has a form with a drop-down called document type and for every document there is a related questions with input fields to answers in form of  drop-down or textbox. When ever the question is answered another textbox called comments need to append all answers with some extra string concatenation. I am using knockout js in front end and .net framework MVC in backend

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a `KnockoutJS` component for showing a question.  Then you can easily add or remote HTML items and have them repeated for each question.